# Deserializing objects sent through ObjectOutpoutStream

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I'm having issues while trying to receive a 2-d/ array of `String` through the `ObjectOutputStream`.
My code for sending the array is :

```
String [][] sendable = new String [n][5];
ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
os.writeObject(sendable);
```

Assume my array is initialized with all the values, how can I unpack the received data back into a 2-d array ? My first approach was this but it's been causing problems as I'm relatively new to Java and socket programming.

```
ObjectInputStream ois =new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
String insa[][] = null;         

try{
    insa= (String[][]) ois.readObject();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println(insa[0][1]);
```

How can I retrieve the 2-d array sent as an object ?

Comment: At a glance, that should work.  What problems are you seeing?

Comment: The client application is not responding after the objectinputstream declaration . it is as its stuck in a while loop awaiting input

Comment: I suggest it is stuck in the ObjectInputStream constructor.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to construct the ObjectOutputStream before the ObjectInputStream, at both ends. Otherwise the peers can deadlock reading the object stream header.
2. You need to construct both streams once for the life of the socket, not once per send or receive.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest flushing os after writing sendable:

```
os.writeObject(sendable);
os.flush();
```

You probably also want to call os.flush() immediately after constructor as recommended by official docs:

> Creates an ObjectOutputStream that writes to the specified OutputStream. This constructor writes the serialization stream header to the underlying stream; callers may wish to flush the stream immediately to ensure that constructors for receiving ObjectInputStreams will not block when reading the header.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#ObjectOutputStream%28java.io.OutputStream%29

Comment: Unnecessary with that code. If there was a BufferedOutputStream you would be correct.

Comment: ObjectOutputStream is not a BufferedOutputStream but it does have an internal buffer.
That's why it implements Flushable interface and provides a flush() method.
See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#flush%28%29

Comment: Certainly, but it doesn't need flushing after you call writeObject().